# Use AngularJS in website without view template

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm developing a mobile app with AngularJS+Ionic+PHP+MySQL and is very fantastic and simply and so fast to develop.
Now I've to make a support website for that app, and I would use part of the same code to easy develop but I don't like single page for a website, so I prefer use jquery...
My question is: is it possible use in some page angularJS without setting a view template (so use the same app.js with controller and directory ect..) without $urlRouterProvider?

Comment: Yes... you don't need to make a your site a SPA to use Angular, you can just include it, define a controller, and go.

Comment: OK, I'm tryng....but for use $stateParams???